# Python - Django site admin page is empty after logged in

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game. My Django site admin page is appearing blank and I am not able to solve it.

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

GAME_STATUS_CHOICES ={
    ('F','First Player to move'),
    ('S', 'Second Player to move'),
    ('W', 'First Player Wins'),
    ('L', 'Second player Wins'),
    ('D', 'Draw')
}

class GameQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def games_for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(
            Q(first_player = user) | Q(second_player = user) 
    )

def active(self):
    return  self.filter(
        Q(status='F') | Q(status='S')
    )


class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 
        "game_first_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 
        "game_second_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='F', 
    choices=GAME_STATUS_CHOICES)
    objects =  GameQuerySet.as_manager()
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} vs {1}".format(
            self.first_player, self.second_player)

class Move(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField() # X and Y co-ordinates
    y = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank= True)
    by_first_player = models.BooleanField()
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import  Game, Move

admin.site.register(Move)
@admin.register(Game)
class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','first_player','second_player','status')
    list_editable = ('status',)
```

I'm a newbie to Django. I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. Couldn't find the answers.

My settings.py seems to fine,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'gameplay',
     'player',
]
```

Comment: Why the two `admin.site.register` lines?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `admin.site.register`. The root of problem is most likely in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, it seems to me, that they could be blank.

Comment: @vishesh_shell my `INSTALLED_APPS` is fine i dont find any problem with that

Answer (score 0):

On your settings file make sure your admin app is listed first

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_filters',

)
```

in admin - register to admin after admin class code (i know the admin decorator should work ....)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import  Game, Move

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','first_player','second_player','status')
    list_editable = ('status',)

class MoveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = MoveAdmin._meta.get_all_field_names()


admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
admin.site.register(Move, Moveadmin)
```

Comment: my admin app is listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. I dont know why its showing blank for me

Comment: tried your update but no results the admin site is empty as before

Comment: Did  you ever run 'python manage.py migrate'? I mean initial migrate for the project. Also, add site to installed apps

Comment: I would check if you are running the runserver command from the virtual env where the code lives, or maybe from out side the docker or virtual machine.
It should work, it is something easy that u do not see.
Try a new project from scratch and activate the admin.